# Sort items by creation time in firebase storage in Android

Tags: firebase, sorting, kotlin, task, storage

I need to sort items in a firebase folder by creation time. The creation times are in the metadata of the item.

I have been able to do it, but I feel that there is a better way to accomplish it using the listener and the "Tasks" utility class.

I've tried to follow [this guide](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-3_29.html?utm_campaign=Firebase_culture_education_general_en_10-04-16&utm_source=Firebase&utm_medium=blog#heading=h.qjejnpwlb5os) but my use cases is more complex

getMedatada documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getMetadata()

getCreationTimeMillis documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageMetadata#getCreationTimeMillis()

This is my code:

```
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(category).listAll().addOnSuccessListener {
        val listOfTalks = mutableListOf<Task<StorageMetadata>>()
        val items = it.items
        items.forEach { listOfTalks.add(it.metadata) } // collecting the list of task for getting the metadata

        val metadataTasks = Tasks.whenAllComplete(listOfTalks) 
        // wait fore all the metadata
        metadataTasks.addOnSuccessListener {
           // put them in a helper class and sort
            val sortedBy = it.map {
                val storageMetadata = it.result as StorageMetadata
                ReferenceAndTimeForSorting(
                    storageMetadata.reference!!,
                    storageMetadata.creationTimeMillis
                )
            }.sortedByDescending { it.timestamp }
            // keep al the references int the result
            storageReferenceList.addAll(sortedBy.map { it.reference })
        }

        metadataTasks.addOnFailureListener {
            // if there is an error getting the metadata, keep the default sorting
            storageReferenceList.addAll(items)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Firebase STORAGE does not have this functionality @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we ended up with:

```
 FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
            .reference
            .child(category)
            .listAll()
            .addOnSuccessListener { listAllResult ->
                val metadataTaskList = listAllResult.items.map { it.metadata }
                Tasks.whenAllComplete(metadataTaskList)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { taskList ->
                        val storageReferenceList = taskList
                            .map { it.result as StorageMetadata }
                            .sortedByDescending { it.creationTimeMillis }
                            .mapNotNull { it.reference }
                        updateGallery(storageReferenceList)
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        updateGallery(listAllResult.items)
                    }
            }
```